# uploading a file (photo), save it to a local folder as a string (to the Database) and show it from the specific folder as jpg

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, upload

i got this project in React , and the Admin can add Vacations manually (in modal bootstrap) - and show it on the screen.
one of the requirements is that he can upload an existing file (photo) which will use as a photo of the vacation he adds.
the picture need to be sent to the server as and be save to Uploads file (of all the images of the vacations) , and be saves as a string (in the database) to the location of the specific folder(and to be shown on the screen of course.)
im trying to use npm express-fileupload / save it as base 64 to image but both of the methods are not working...

```
 router.post('/addvacation', async (req, res, next) => { 
            console.log(req.body);
            const imgPath = 'should be uploaded to the Uploads file and make it as a string to the location of the specific folder.'; 
//saveImage(req.body.image,req.body.name);


            let insertQuery = `
         INSERT INTO users.vacations (name, price, start, end, followers ,image, description ) 
         VALUES ('${req.body.name}' , ${req.body.price},'${req.body.start}' , '${req.body.end}', '[]' , '${imgPath}',  '${req.body.description}' )

         `; 
            const itemData = {...req.body,image: imgPath };
            try {
                await pool.query(insertQuery); 
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.error(e.message);
                res.status(401).json("Fail");
                return;
            }

            ws.io.emit('add', itemData);
            res.status(200).json("OK");  
        });
```

i also tried to use this code but it didnt work also.

```
// function saveImage(data,name) {
    //     var fs = require('fs');

    //     var bytes = data.split("%");

    //     var b = new Buffer(bytes.length);
    //     var c = "";
    //     for (var i = 0;i < bytes.length;i++) {
    //         b[i] = bytes[i];
    //         c = c + " " + bytes[i]
    //     }

    //     fs.writeFile(`../public/uploads/${name}.jpg`, c,  "binary",function(err) {
    //         if(err) {
    //             console.log(err);
    //         } else {
    //             console.log("The file was saved!");
    //         }
    //     });

    //     return `localhost:3000/public/uploads/${id}.jpg`;
    // }
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload file again with different name which was already uploaded into directory?

Comment: i am trying  to upload a file and save it to a specific folder and than to save it to the Database as a src to the uploaded file (photo) , so ill have access to it and i could show it on the screen.

Comment: Use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty package. This is very easy to use.